# Installing Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

I have followed this tutorial (http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-linux#.URj9weCy1Nh) to install tomcat on debian wheezy using the following environment variables:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-   tomcat-7.0.35/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

I have given the tomcat user a bash login and when I run ./startup.sh nothing happens and no port opens. Running version.sh gives me:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo. Program will exit.

Any ideas what is missing ?

Comment: What happens if you add `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/lib/` to the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install complete, Compatible `JDK from Oracle (SUN) or IBM`
- Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the root directory of
  the compatible JDK

> $`JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01`
>
> $ `export JAVA_HOME`

- Put the compatibale JDK's bin directory on the front of your `PATH`
  environment variable.

> `$    PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
>
> `$    export PATH`

- Find the java executable of the incompatible JDK, usually
  `/usr/bin/java` and move it out of the way, like this:

> $`cd /usr/java`
>
> $`mv java java.moved`

- Then, check to make sure your java executable points to the JDK you
  have installed:

> `$ which java`
>
> `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/bin/java`

Comment: I did that but now when I run version.sh I get ./catalina.sh: 506: ./catalina.sh: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/java: not found

and it is definitely there...

Comment: Did you export PATH and JAVA_HOME?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13
$ echo $PATH
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Comment: Run script in debug mode:  sh -x ./catalina.sh version

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I installed the 32 bit version for my x86_64 machine. I will update later...

Comment: It should work! with properly installed package!!!

Comment: ./version.sh gives

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo**

and java works fine now.

Comment: By the way, it seems that I do not have **bootstrap.jar** and **tomcat-juli.jar**

Comment: Here is your answer! http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html

Comment: generally they located inside [Tomcat-base]/bin directory

Comment: Using CLASSPATH: /opt/tomcat6.0/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat6.0/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: I do not get how this solves the problem I still missing the jar files. Building from source with ant gives compile time java error messages.

Comment: Which tomcat package you are using: I am using http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.36/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.36.tar.gz  and it has those files :)

Comment: I was trying to use the source package, the binary one works fine. I just got myself into a nightmare for no reason....Anyway, thanks very much for your suggestions.